# Child process event for updated stdout

Tags: node.js, stdout, 7zip

Currently my code has a spawn of a 7zip. When you normally call the 7zip cli, it will have a progress message which updates as it goes:

```
> 7z u archive.7z dir 

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive:
14 folders, 37 files, 45418359 bytes (44 MiB)
...

// this part gets updated
22% 7 + dir/image.png
```

My code is currently logging the stdout correctly, but it is not logging the updates:

```js
const child = spawn('7z', ['u', 'archive.7z', 'dir'], { shell: true });
child.stdout.on("data", data => console.log("" + data));
```

I've noticed that the events resume and readable get called on `child.stdout` after the static content is logged but still can't figure out what to do after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the output stream for the progress to either `stdout` or `stderr` respectively with the following flag.

> -bs{o|e|p}{0|1|2} : set output stream for output/error/progress line

```js
// File: main.js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('7z', ['u', '-bsp1', 'archive.7z', 'dir']);
// -bsp1 = stdout
child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
// -bsp2 = stderr
// child.stderr.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
```

```sh
$ node main.js 

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz (306C3),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive:
1 folder, 1 file, 2877227008 bytes (2744 MiB)

Creating archive: archive.7z

Items to compress: 2

  0%
  0% + dir/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso
  1% + dir/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso
  2% + dir/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso
  3% + dir/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso
  4% + dir/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso
```